# How to kill a thread which has a while(true)?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, threadpool

I am trying to close all my thread in my threadpool.

Usually I try:

```
        while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {...
```

To close the while loop...

But I have one Thread which only consists about

```
        while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {//which is true
```

This is how I close the threads:

```
pool.shutdownNow();
```

So how would you close such a Thread?

Comment: you need to know exit condition for that thread....

Comment: Does [Thread.interrupt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt()) work for you?

Comment: when you have the above while loops in a method of your class which `extends Thread`, you can use `this.isInterrupted()` instead of `Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()`.

Comment: @Philipp Hopefully OP **doesn't extend `Thread`**.

Comment: That condition will become false when you call `shutdownNow`, because that method interrupts the threads in the loop, and the loop will exit. Not sure I understand your question.

Comment: @Marko Topolnik: What would be wrong with that? I read multiple tutorials about multithreading in Java which did that.

Comment: @Philipp It is a widely accepted best practice. Simply google for "java extend Thread" to find all about it. The tutorials are obviously doing their readers a disservice.

Comment: Even the official documentation does it: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html

Comment: @Philipp The official documentation is not there to recommend, but to... well, *document*, in this case the fact that there are indeed two ways to provide an entry point to a `Thread` instance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can add a `volatile` boolean `flag`.

```
public class Worker implements Runnable {

    volatile boolean cancel = false;
    @Override
    public void run() {

        while (!cancel) {
            // Do Something here
        }
    }

    public void cancel() {
        cancel = true;
    }
}
```

Now you can just call

```
worker.cancel();
```

**Update:**

From Java doc of [shutdownNow()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdownNow%28%29)

> Attempts to stop all actively executing tasks, halts the processing of waiting tasks, and returns a list of the tasks that were awaiting execution.
>
> here are no guarantees beyond best-effort attempts to stop processing actively executing tasks. For example, typical implementations will cancel via **Thread.interrupt()**, so any task that **fails to respond to interrupts may never terminate**.

So either you will have to define your interruption policy by preserving the interrupts

```
  catch (InterruptedException ie) {
     // Preserve interrupt status
     Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
   }
```

Comment: -1 This is redundant - why not use the interruption mechanism only?

Comment: @AmitD You do need that negation in there :)

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik He has one thread which has interrupt status false so it will never enter into while if negation is there. I think there is difference in the wording.

Comment: @AmitD Not following you. (interrupt==false) => (!interrupt true), so the condition is always true. OP definitely doesn't suffer from the loop never  being entered, but from being unable to break it.

Comment: Yes that is he want to do he want to break that thread. You both created such a confusion in my head. :(

Comment: @assylias  `!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()`== true  negation is true which means the interrupt is never set to current thread.So he wanted some mechanism where he can do that.

Comment: @AmitD The mechanism of choice would be the interruption mechanism. `Thread.interrupt` is automatically called by `ExecutorService.shutdownNow()`.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I knew that but he had some case where interrupt was swallowed and then he was not able to terminate the program. Now `boolean flag` is another exit policy for threads. Either he has to set `interrupt()` flag or use other policy choice is OP's. We are not sure why interruption is swallowed.

Comment: In my view, the first line of advice would be "check where it's swallowed" and only as a last resort workaround use a custom mechanism since this involves much more code, bringing in new ways for the code to fail.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of that you might use a self created flag as condition for the while loop.

```
public class MyClass implements Runnable
{

    private volatile boolean running = true;

    public void stopRunning()
    {
        running = false;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        while (running)
        {

        }
        // shutdown stuff here
    }

}
```

Now, to stop it, just call:

```
myClassObject.stopRunning();
```

This will let the code finish normally.

Answer (score 2):

If you have implemented this as you have described, it should just work.

When you call `pool.shutdownNow()` it is supposed to interrupt all worker threads that are currently active.  Assuming that the application specific `run()` methods check the interrupted flag and terminate themselves when they find it set, your threads should shutdown.

There is really no need to add a different mechanism using an *ad hoc* cancel flag ... or some such.

---

Incidentally, there are a couple reasons why `interrupt()` is better than *ad hoc* cancellation:

- Standard APIs like ExecutorService use it.
- Various low-level API methods like `sleep`, `wait`, `join` and some I/O methods are sensitive to it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a `java.util.concurrent` ExecutorService implementation, then it will definitely send an `interrupt` signal to all the threads in its thread pool. The problem with your rogue task may be that the loop doesn't in fact iterate, but blocks somewhere within, so the `interrupted` status is not getting checked at all.

Yet another problem you may have: the while loop runs some code that **catches InterruptedException** without handling it properly, effectively **swallowing the interrupt signal**. This is a common coding mistake and in most cases due to the ugly truth that `InterruptedException` is checked.

Comment: @assylias Heh heh, and not just today :)